# QTableView not showing all of the data from an SQLite database

Tags: qt, sqlite, qtableview, qsortfilterproxymodel, qsqlquerymodel

I have a simple application with a [QTableView](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/QTableView.html#details) and a [QLineEdit](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/QLineEdit.html#details) and I'm using [QSqlQueryModel](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/QSqlQueryModel.html#details) and [QSortFilterProxyModel](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsortfilterproxymodel.html#details) to get the data from a table in a SQLite3 database and filter the results (with [setFilterFixedString(the text from the QLineEdit)](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsortfilterproxymodel.html#setFilterFixedString)). The table in the database is 8611 rows big.

When first loaded, the tableview does not seem to be showing all of the rows in the database. When I apply a string to the filter (put some text on QLineEdit) not all of the expected results are showing; I have to delete the text from the QLineEdit and scroll down to the end of the tableview (it updates from the database?!) then the problem disappears: I have all of the results as from the database.

Is it a known bug with QTableView? How to solve this problem?

Thank you.

P.S: this is the essential parts from my application regarding this problem.

`mainwindow.h`

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QMessageBox>
#include <QtSql>

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

private slots:
    void on_searchEdit_textChanged(const QString &arg1);

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    QSqlQueryModel *model;
    QSortFilterProxyModel *proxyModel;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

`mainwindow.cpp`

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE");
    db.setDatabaseName("dpm.db");
    if (!db.open()) { }
    model = new QSqlQueryModel(this);
    model->setQuery(QString("SELECT specialite as Spécialité, dci as DCI FROM medocs"), db);
    proxyModel = new QSortFilterProxyModel(this);
    proxyModel->setSourceModel(model);
    proxyModel->setFilterCaseSensitivity(Qt::CaseInsensitive);
    ui->listeTable->setModel(proxyModel);
    ui->listeTable->show();
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::on_searchEdit_textChanged(const QString &medoc)
{
    proxyModel->setFilterFixedString(medoc);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It turned out Qt's SQLite driver inserts rows into the model in steps of 256 rows. I had to fetch all of the results with [fetchMore()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#canFetchMore).

```
while(model->canFetchMore()) model->fetchMore();
```

See [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27393939/2124090) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27372480/2124090).